# How to launch WhatsApp by flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to make page for user from this page user can launch whatsapp app by flutter.

```
 flutter_launch: ^0.2.0
```

Code of launch whatsapp I get it from pub.dev web.But I have one problem with the application starting I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_launch' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I use Intellij IDEA to create my app.I was don't select kotlin at start project I was select java.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't know where the error is. I tried to locate the error, but I could not locate it.Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package and use it to launch the What's App's link.

[What's App: How to use click to chat](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) and use the following variables:

```
const phone = '+20123456789';
var whatsappUrl = "whatsapp://send?phone=$phone";
```

then implement it in an onPressed function:

```
onPressed: () async {
    if (await launcher.canLaunch(whatsappUrl)) {
        await launcher.launch(whatsappUrl);
    } else {
        _showDialog(
        context,
        title: 'Error',
        msg: 'Please make sure that you have whatsapp installed',
        );
    }
},
```